# Proving a Probability Theory Related Statement

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We are given a statement telling us that A and B are two events. We need to prove that 
$$\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-1 \leq \Pr(A \cap B) \leq \Pr(A \cup B) \leq \Pr(A)+\Pr(B).$$

I was able to prove that $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-1 \leq \Pr(A \cap B)$, but am stuck proving the rest of the statement. I just used the fact that $\Pr(A \cup B) \leq 1$ to prove that part. How would I prove the rest of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**

Note that $A\cap B\subseteq A\cup B$ and use the montonicity of measure. For the last inequality use

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: So basically we just write A∩B⊆A∪B and this implies that A∩B≤A∪B right?

Comment: $E\subseteq F$ implies $Pr(E)\leq Pr(F)$, yes.  This is a part of the definition of a measure and therefore of probability as well.

Comment: To prove this: Pr(A∪B)≤Pr(A)+Pr(B) how would we eliminate the P(A∩B) part an convert the statement to an inequality?

Comment: @Smith Daniel Note that $P(A\cup B)-P(A)-P(B)=-P(A\cap B)\leq 0$

Comment: We just note that down? No proof?

Comment: @SmithDaniel See Edit to comment.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. BTW is there any kind of reference or cheat sheet where I can brush up on these concepts?

Comment: @SmithDaniel the definitions are always a good place to start.  [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) for the list of probability axioms and commonly used consequences.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Inclusion-exclusion principle states that

$Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$

Law of total probability implies that

$Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A\cap B')+Pr(A\cap B)+Pr(A'\cap B)$